# Why does each equation of a vector space remove a dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Im a student studying linear algebra and my professor has said this to me on the fly.
I have encountered that as long as the equation is not trivial ($1 = 1$), or equations are not the same ($y = x$, $x = y$), then each equation of a vector space removes 1 dimension of the vector space it is based on.
For example the vector space $W$:

$W = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x=y\}$

then a basis for $W$ could be: $\{(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$

$\dim(\mathbb{R}^3)=3$

but $\dim(W)=2$

so my question is why does this happen? if it even is true

Comment: Because $W$ doesn't include the entire space $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the equation $x=y$ restricts which values are allowable. Alternative you can consider $x-y=0$ as defining the kernel of an orthogonal projection onto $W$. Since $x-y=0$ has non-trivial solutions it has a non-trivial kernel which is how we can identify it as a projection.

Comment: Note that we're talking about equations in which the $x$, $y$, and $z$ terms are **linear**. If you see $x^2$ in an equation then it's the wrong kind of equation. Also, if there's a constant term that isn't $0$ and can't be eliminated, It's the wrong kind of equation.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

I think it helps to think geometrically. In three dimensions the solutions to an equation like
$$
ax + by +cz = 0
$$
form a plane. That has dimension $2 = 3-1$.

If you have another such equation it defines another plane (unless it happens to be proportional to this equation). The intersection of those two planes is a line, so dimension $3-2 =1$.

Three planes (in general position) intersect in a point, with dimension $3-3=0$.

You can't see the pictures in higher dimensions but the geometry works the same way. You use the algebra of linear independence to  formalize that geometric intuition.